# Collapse entire table on click with animation

Tags: html, css, animation, reactjs

I am have a table where I would like to be able to click on the table header row and that will collapse the rest of the table leaving only the header row (and expand back out). With a good deal of struggle I was able to get the table to actually change it's height on click, but haven't been able to get the animation to trigger. Here is the css that I have so far:

```
table {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.collapsed {
  animation-name: collapse;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes collapse {
  from { height: 100%; }
  to { height: 40px; }
}

/* This is the javascript that is trigger on click */
this.refs.ruleslisttable.classList.toggle("ruleSetInfo__rule-list-table--collapsed");
```

The code above doesn't even trigger the new height when I toggle the class on the table, but has been my attempt at getting the animation in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need to do it with `keyframe` animation.

You could do it just by adding a `transition` rule to the `table` element, like this:

```
table {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 2s ease-in;
}

.collapsed {
    height: 40px;
}
```

What this does, is tell the browser to transition the `height` of the `table` from 100% to 40px and vice cersa over a duration of 2s with an [`ease-in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function) function

For more info you can read the entry about the transition property at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)

Cheers

**UPDATE:**

In your current setup I suppose the parent of the `table` element does not have a strictly defined height.

The way the percentage based height works is like this: The element gets the 100% of its parent height.

**However** when you do not specify a height for the parent, be it in `px`, `em`, `rem`, `vh` or what have you, the child with `height: 100%` is like having `height: auto`. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/height)

And here is the actual problem: **You cannot transition from `auto` to any other value, like `%`, `px` etc.**

You can only transition from one *defined* value (!== `auto`) to any other defined value. e.g. from `px` to `rem`, etc

And this is why your transition is not working.

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkarajohn/5js63snr/)
 I made. Play with the `#cont` element's height and see what happens.

So, in short: **You will either have to give a strict height to your table, or, if you want to keep it percentage based, give a strict height to its parent element.**

Comment: So sadly when that is the CSS and I click, there is a 2s delay and then the height changes. It doesn't actually ease... :/

Comment: Hmm. Could you maybe provide the HTML, or a sample HTML, and some of the JS you are using?

Comment: Sure though there isn't much. It simply toggles the class on the DOM element. So the height is successfully changing, but with no animation.

Comment: Ah, ok. Got it. You cannot transition from percentage based values to anty-other-unit value. I will update my answer with more info, just give me 5 minutes to write it.

Comment: Updated the answer, you can check it out.